# Redirect with htaccess always append ?_route_

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I add the code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /san-pham/khuyen-mai/ /khuyen-mai
```

In default .htaccess file in opencart but the result will return:

```
http://myphamthiennhien.com/khuyen-mai?_route_=san-pham/khuyen-mai
```

You can test it here
http://myphamthiennhien.com/san-pham/khuyen-mai/

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite` to strip off query-string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^san-pham/khuyen-mai/ /khuyen-mai? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Note `?` in the end, that is required to strip query string.